# installation npm failed for an existing project with angular 4

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-install, node-modules

I'm begginer on angular 4. I tried to import an existing project on angular 4 to my local machine.
I used npm install to get nodes_modules using the package.json of the project, but I got this error :
[image]

This is the error log:

```
36096 warn @angular/material-moment-adapter@5.2.5 requires a peer of @angular/material@5.2.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
36097 warn bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.12.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
36098 warn ngx-malihu-scrollbar@1.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.4.0 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
36099 warn angular2-perfect-scrollbar@2.0.6 requires a peer of @angular/common@^2.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
36100 warn angular2-perfect-scrollbar@2.0.6 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
36101 warn angular2-perfect-scrollbar@2.0.6 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@^2.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
36102 warn angular2-perfect-scrollbar@2.0.6 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.7.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
36103 warn @angular/compiler-cli@5.0.2 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.4.2 <2.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
36104 warn @angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.52 requires a peer of @angular-devkit/core@0.0.29 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
36105 warn @schematics/angular@0.1.17 requires a peer of @angular-devkit/core@0.0.29 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
36106 warn tsickle@0.24.1 requires a peer of typescript@2.4.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
36110 verbose stack Error: node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
36111 verbose pkgid node-sass@4.7.2
36113 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.14393
36114 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
36115 verbose node v10.13.0
36116 verbose npm  v6.4.1
36117 error code ELIFECYCLE
36118 error errno 1
36119 error node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
36119 error Exit status 1
36120 error Failed at the node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall script.
36120 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
36121 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

this is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "front-angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "5.0.0-rc0",
    "@angular/common": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "5.0.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "2.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "7.0.1",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "11.1.2",
    "angular2-text-mask": "8.0.4",
    "angular2-wizard": "0.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.2",
    "compass-mixins": "0.12.10",
    "devextreme": "^17.2.7",
    "devextreme-angular": "^17.2.7",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "material-design-iconic-font": "2.2.0",
    "mdi": "2.0.46",
    "moment": "^2.22.0",
    "multi-brand-colors": "1.1.3",
    "ng2-password-strength-bar": "1.1.3",
    "ng2-responsive": "0.8.4",
    "ng2-search-filter": "0.3.1",
    "ng2-validation": "4.2.0",
    "ng2-webstorage": "2.0.0",
    "ngbox": "0.0.15",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "2.0.0-beta.8",
    "ngx-ckeditor": "0.1.1",
    "ngx-malihu-scrollbar": "1.2.2",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "5.0.2",
    "ngx-uploader": "4.2.1",
    "node-sass": "4.7.2",
    "sweetalert2": "^7.18.0",
    "ts-helper": "0.0.1",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.5.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "5.0.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.2",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "8.0.53",
    "angular2-perfect-scrollbar": "2.0.6",
    "codelyzer": "4.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.2.3",
    "jasmine-core": "2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "5.2.0",
    "ts-node": "3.3.0",
    "tslint": "5.8.0",
    "typescript": "2.6.1"
  }
}
```

I'm using :
npm : v6.4.1
node: v10.13.0

Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Please, copy/paste the package.json content.

Comment: @NeauAdrien I just update my post, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You use Windows. Npm says windows build tools are not up to date. You have to upgrade the windows build tools. Try this command: `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`

Also, take a look here. Maybe it can help: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/629#issuecomment-153196245

Comment: Did you take a look at the thread I linked? You can also take a look at it: https://github.com/chjj/pty.js/issues/60. Many people have this kind of problem... And many ways to resolve it.

Comment: Not Working for me